# newdf = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis = 0),now every line of newdf is a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

Try this code please :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
newdf = pd.concat([df1,df2] , axis = 0)
print type(newdf.loc[0])
```

The result is 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame';

but I think it's should be a 'Series'.

Is that a bug or I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It should be a `DataFrame`, as after concatenating you have two rows with index 0. `newdf.loc[0]` returns a 2x4 `DataFrame`

Specifically, in my case it returns a `DataFrame` like this:

```
Out[50]: 
      a         b         c         d
0  1.302054 -0.274331 -1.131744 -1.736018
0  0.811842 -1.225765  1.258529  0.647977
```

To get series you can use `ignore_index` parameter in `pd.concat` - then the index values will be from 0 to 4, not 0,1,2,0,1:

```
newdf = pd.concat([df1,df2] , axis = 0, ignore_index=True)
```